# If $f$ is a continuous and either open or closed map, but not surjective, it's not a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

There's a theorem (9.2) in Willard's General Topology which says that if $f$ is a continuous and either open or closed function between two topological spaces, then $f$ is a quotient map, but he's not assuming (or at least he doesn't say it) that $f$ is surjective, so I was wondering if he is assuming that or if $f$ is automatically surjective if it is continuous and either open or closed.

Comment: can you cite the theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's a typo, the word "onto" should be there somewhere. Moreover, the proof uses $f[f^{-1}(U)]=U$ which is not true in general if $f$ is not surjective.

A continuous and open map need not be onto, consider the identity function $id:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It’s implicit that $f$ is onto, from the discussion before the theorem. He should have included it though, for reference. In Willard, open maps need not be onto.